# knockoutjs bindind observablearray doent work

Tags: knockout.js

im trying to get video feeds from youtube through a 'search' function. i push data in an observablearray but the BINDING always fail.

i have this viewModel like this :

```
var videoFeeds = ko.observableArray();
var vm = {
    videoFeeds: videoFeeds,
    search: search
};
function search(value) {
    value = value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '+');

    var options = {
        url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/?q=' + value + '&max-results=10&alt=json&v=2',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    };

    $.ajax(options)
        .done(function (data) {
            videoFeeds([]);
            for (var k in data.feed.entry)
            {
                var videoFeed = {
                    title : data.feed.entry[k].media$group.media$title.$t,
                    id : data.feed.entry[k].media$group.yt$videoid.$t,
                    author: data.feed.entry[k].author[0].name.$t
                };

                videoFeeds().push(videoFeed);
            }
            for (var k in videoFeeds())
            {
                console.log('title : ' + videoFeeds()[k].title);
            }
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

the view s like this :

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: videoFeeds">
    <li data-bind="text: title"></li>
</ul>
```

as you can see i log the 'title' of each feed into the console , it works fine, the array is updated. But i still cant see the 'title' of the feeds in my view.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `videoFeeds().push(videoFeed)` try updating the View Models property directory by saying `vm.videoFeeds.push(videoFeed)`.

When you create the view model, you are passing in a preference to the `videoFeeds` array, however, once you start adding items, you should be working only with the View Models array.

For readability, it might be better to declare the ViewModel like this:

```
var vm = {
    videoFeeds: ko.observableArray(),
    search: search
};
```

and getting rid of the initial array definition all together.

Comment: You are right `videoFeeds().push(videoFeed)` was the problem, thanks very much mate for your help. about the readability i agree with you this is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem, please mark as answer, too. Thanks!